# here document and the readonly flag and command substitution in POSIX shells

Tags: posix, sh

The following text receives different treatment by two Unix shells in POSIX mode:

```
readonly a=$(cat - <<'EOF'
1st
2nd
EOF
)
```

One shell (*bash(1)* --posix) makes `$a` have "1st 2nd" while the other rejects, saying that

> dash: 1: readonly: 2nd: bad variable name

Both shells agree once `readonly` is dropped, i.e. when `a` is a fresh variable assigned to RHS.

Is one of the shells more correct than the other?

Using either shell, I can assign `a` first and then mark it `readonly`, so there is a solution.  Still, rewriting would then seem a requirement when porting to *dash(1)* (version 0.5.7-4ubuntu1). Is it a bug in *dash*?

**Update**: Learning from chepner's answer (words, quoting), it seems worth mentioning some gotchas found along the way. Thus,

```
readonly a=$*             ; echo a $a
b=$*         ; readonly b ; echo b $b
readonly c="$*"           ; echo c $c
```

produces different behavior among all of *bash*, *dash*, *posh*, *zsh*, including errors depending on text in `$*`. Similar issues when exchanging `readonly` for `local` by way of testing.

Comment: Bash is Bash, Dash is (or tries to be) POSIX. See [**POSIX Programmers Guide**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) Bash provides a lot of functionality, including additional keywords not present in POSIX shell. Additionally what each distro provides as POSIX mode differs a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR This may be a case of undefined behavior, where a shell is free to treat a `name=value` argument to `readonly` as either a true assignment statement or a regular string argument. This will affect how word-splitting is applied to the value.

---

I think this is a case where `dash` is correct. In a normal assignment, such as

```
a=$(cat - <<'EOF'
1st
2nd
EOF
)
```

the right-hand side is not subject to word-splitting. The result of the command substitution is a string with two embedded newlines which is assigned to the variable.

`readonly`, however, is a command itself; the `name=value` syntax is an ordinary argument, not an assignment statement, and as such is subject to word-splitting. The command substitution produces a string with embedded newlines as before, but since it is not quoted, those newlines are treated as arbitrary whitespace. The result is equivalent to

```
readonly a=1st 2nd
```

which is clearly in error. As you might expect, you get the intended assignment if you quote the command substitution (protecting the newlines):

```
readonly a="$(cat - <<'EOF'
1st
2nd
EOF
)"
```

`zsh` produces the same error as `dash`:

```
% readonly a=$(cat - <<'EOF'
cmdsubst heredoc> 1st
cmdsubst heredoc> 2nd
cmdsubst heredoc> EOF
cmdsubst> )
readonly: not an identifier: 2nd
192%
```

`bash` and `ksh` exhibit the same behavior. The `bash` man page doesn't give any hint as to why quoting isn't necessary, although the `ksh` man page does allude to the argument to `readonly` as being a true assignment (emphasis mine):

> Variable Assignments.
>
> One  or  more variable assignments can start a simple command or **can be
>          arguments to the typeset, enum, export, or  readonly**  special  built-in
>          commands